# Change 'href' attribute in AJAX enabled links

Tags: 7, ajax

I have some links with the class `use-ajax`. Everything works fine with default settings.

The problem is that at some point I need to change the `href` attribute of a link and make the ajax call to the new url, which is not working. The call is made to the initial url of that link.

I tried to reattach behaviours but this doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody knows how to do it I think this might help:

```
var element_settings = {};
element_settings.url = $(this).attr('href');
element_settings.event = 'click';
element_settings.progress = {
  type: 'throbber',
  message: ''
};
var base = $(this).attr('id');
Drupal.ajax[base] = new Drupal.ajax( base, this, element_settings );

$(this).unbind(Drupal.ajax[base].event);

$(this).bind(Drupal.ajax[base].event, function (event) {
  return Drupal.ajax[base].eventResponse(this, event);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Drupal link based Ajax, correspond to a `Drupal.ajax['#id']` element object and drupal works with them not with DOM Objects.

So you don't have to change the href attribute you need to change the URL where it's doing POST in the `Drupal.ajax` element, in this case do this:

```
// Confirm structure first executing on console 'Drupal.ajax['#id'].options.url'
var href = 'hook_url/ajax/parameter1/parameter2';

// And change the href POST parameter
Drupal.ajax['#id'].options.url = href;
```

And it's done!

Comment: This worked fine for me. Note that if you're working with a url containing 'nojs' you'll need to clean that up. Also, links don't usually have ids, so I had to add some.

Comment: You excellent man, this just solved all of my problems

Answer (score 0):

in case your link has no ID attribute, here is another solution:

```
var href = oldhref.replace('/watch/', '/unwatch/'); //your new url
var elem = $('.watchthis a'); // the link element 
elem.attr('href', href);
var n = Drupal.ajax.instances.length;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (Drupal.ajax.instances[i].element == elem[0]) {
    Drupal.ajax.instances[i].options.url = href+'?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax';
  }
}
```

Comment: Your talking Drupal8 ;)