# Dynamic arguments in an AJAX link

Tags: ajax, javascript

I have a link that uses Drupal's `use-ajax` CSS class to AJAX-load some node teasers. The callback for the link uses arguments to set a range in the Entity Field Query used to return the teasers:

```
function marketplace_ajax_list_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['marketplace_ajax_list_callback/%/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'marketplace_ajax_list_response',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2, 3),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}

function marketplace_ajax_list_response($type='ajax', $collection_nid, $start, $page_limit) {
  if ($type == 'ajax') {
    $output = marketplace_ajax_list_collection_latest_content($collection_nid, $start, $page_limit);
    $commands = array();
    $commands[] = ajax_command_append('#ajax-target', $output);
    $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
    ajax_deliver($page);
  }
}

function marketplace_ajax_list_collection_latest_content($collection_nid, $start=0, $page_limit=10) {
  $q = new \EntityFieldQuery();
  $q->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', array('story', 'reader'))
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
      ->fieldOrderBy('field_date', 'value', 'DESC')
      ->fieldCondition('field_ref_collection', 'nid', $collection_nid, '=');

  // Get the matching items within the range
  $q->range($start, $page_limit);
  $result = $q->execute();
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);

  // Make node teasers
  $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
  $teasers = node_view_multiple($nodes);
  $build = render($teasers);

  return $build;
}
```

When the node teasers are appended to the list, I have a jQuery function that updates the arguments in the AJAX link in order to update the range used in the query:

```
(function ($) {
  var page = 1;
  var page_limit = 10;
  var collection_nid = 12345;

  Drupal.behaviors.marketplace_ajax_list = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      page++;  
      var link = '/marketplace_ajax_list_callback/nojs/' + collection_nid +'/' + (page_limit * page) + '/' + page_limit;
      $moreBtn.attr('href', link); // $moreBtn is the AJAX link
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The link's href changes correctly, with the updated arguments, but the new arguments aren't used in the callback's query - the same arguments are used each time, so the same items appear on each click.

If I take the value that jQuery sets in the href and open the link in another tab, I see the correct items.

So I think the issue has to do with the AJAX behavior getting attached to the link and that's not updated each time the function runs. Is there a command I can add to make that happen?

Answer (score 2):

Solved! I found this post - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/52788/260 - which answered a very similar question, and that changed everything. This issue is essentially a duplicate of that one.

The fix here in my case was to not just change the link's href but to also update the Drupal.ajax object, like this:

```
Drupal.ajax['load-more'].options.url = link;
```

"load-more" is the ID of the AJAX link.