# How to make friends ajax with dynamically created links?

Tags: 7, ajax, navigation

I created leaflet map, when you hover the marker in popup window is a reference to the content.
[image]

I wrote module that loads ajax content in the custom region. For dynamic links added class **use-ajax**, but Drupal does not process them as I needed.
I check and found that static links with class **use-ajax** have additional class **ajax-processing**.
My dynamic link looks like:

```
<a id="jslink" class="use-ajax" href="nojs/problem/83">засорение реки</a>
```

Static link looks like:

```
<a class="use-ajax ajax-processed" href="nojs/node/231">node</a>
```

As I understand Ajax Drupal does not work with dynamic links.
I found issue in what asks in what need to change the href attribute of a link and make the ajax call to the new url.  [Change 'href' attribute in AJAX enabled links](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35245/change-href-attribute-in-ajax-enabled-links)
Wrote JS code but it doesn't work for me.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.test_module = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        $("#jslink").click(function(){
            var href = $("#jslink").attr("href");
            Drupal.ajax['jslink'].options.url = href;

        });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Is it possible to somehow make Drupal to work with dynamic links?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: @Kevin Question is how to do so ajax started working with dynamically created links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, for loading balloons I use module [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) it has js file **ip_geoloc_leaflet_goto_content_on_click.js**
where I add line **Drupal.attachBehaviors();** 
Now it works as designed.

```
jQuery(document).bind('leaflet.feature', function(event, marker, feature) {
  // marker is the feature just added to the map, it could be a polygon too.
  // feature.feature_id is the node ID, as set by ip_geoloc_plugin_style_leaflet.inc
  // Need to set this up for code below.
  // The same code is used for cross-highlighting. See ip_geoloc_leaflet_sync_content.js
  if (feature.feature_id) {
    marker.feature_id = feature.feature_id;
  }
});

jQuery(document).bind('leaflet.map', function(event, map, lMap) {

  if (map.settings.gotoContentOnClick) {
    for (var leaflet_id in lMap._layers) {
      lMap._layers[leaflet_id].on('click', function(e) {
        var id = e.target ? e.target.feature_id : null;
        if (!id && e.layer) id = e.layer.feature_id;
        if (id) {
            //document.location.href = Drupal.settings.basePath + 'node/' + id;
            document.location.href = Drupal.settings.basePath + 'load_node/' + id;
        }
      });
    }
  }
  if (map.settings.openBalloonsOnHover) {
    for (var leaflet_id in lMap._layers) {
      lMap._layers[leaflet_id].on('mouseover', function(e) {
        this.openPopup();
         Drupal.attachBehaviors(); <<<<--------ADDED LINE
      });
    }
  }

});
```