# Dynamically added params for a link not found when the link is opened with a dialog

Tags: 8, javascript, ajax, modal-dialogs

I do not know if it has to do with JavaScript/Ajax or with Drupal's dialog modal. Any advice is appreciated.

On our project we open several links in a modal. For this the link is rendered in the following way:

```php
$classes[] = 'use-ajax';
$renderArray = [
  '#title' => $text,
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#url' => Url::fromRoute($route, $route_params, $url_options),
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => $classes,
    'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
    'data-dialog-options' => json_encode([
      'width' => '95%',
      'dialogClass' => 'ui-dialog--form'
    ]),
    'rel' => 'nofollow'
  ]
];
```

This works as desired: The link is opened in a modal window.

We want to add query parameters to these links dynamically, using JavaScript. This is done by JavaScript in the following way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let positionParameter = getParameterByName('position');
  if (positionParameter) {
    let link_target = $('.politician__questionform__button a.button').attr('href');
    link_target = updateQueryStringParameter(link_target, 'position', positionParameter);
    $('.politician__questionform__button a.button').attr('href', link_target);
  }
})
```

or in this way:

```
Drupal.behaviors.addParametersToQuestionFormLink = {
  attach: function () {
    let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search),
      pk_campaign = urlParams.get('pk_campaign'),
      pk_kwd = urlParams.get('pk_kwd');
    if (pk_campaign || pk_kwd) {
      document.querySelectorAll('a.js-add-parameters').forEach(link => {
        let link_target = link.href;
        if (pk_campaign) {
          link_target = updateQueryStringParameter(link_target, 'pk_campaign', pk_campaign);
        }
        if (pk_kwd) {
          link_target = updateQueryStringParameter(link_target, 'pk_kwd', pk_kwd);
        }
        link.setAttribute('href', link_target);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

In both ways the following can be seen:

- The links get the correct parameters
- When I open these links in a new browser tab the controllers which are used for these links receive the parameters as desired
- But when the links are opened by simply clicking on the link which opens the link in a modal the controllers do not get the parameters set by the JavaScript code.

I bet it has something to do with the fact that the link's href attribute is changed after the document was ready but I thought Drupal's dialog / ajax would use the href attribute value as it is when the click event fires - not the value as it was set on the initial document loading / rendering?! What can I do to make the links have the parameters even when opened via ajax/ modal?

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/253627/49588